# Insert image into Crystal Report using base64 string

Tags: mysql, sql-server, image, crystal-reports, base64

I have a base64 encoded image stored in my database as a blob, and I want to insert it into a Crystal Report without a fileupload field.  I looked all around the internet and can only find ways with a file upload field.

I read somewhere that you need to load a binary code in sql if you want to display an image.
So I have a binary code in MSSQL/MySQL server with varbinary(max) that I load into the crystal report, but the image is still not showing. I do see that it's an image though because I see the red X.

Should I still convert the binary value that I have from sql server to something? Is what I'm trying to do even possible? If so, please describe the way to do it.